# HTML5 and CSS selectors - counter-intuitive?

Tags: css, html

I have a question that's been bugging me ever since I read [this](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/). I've got the general just that CSS selectors with multiple elements work backwards, and that key selector is the one that determines a lot of the efficiency as it narrows down the number of DOM elements that are selected by the prefixing rules.

However this has confused me. Namely in relation to the new HTML5 `<header>`, etc (block-style tags). I use `<header>`, etc. tags to avoid using the HTML structure of `<div class="header">`. Why would I bother to use the `<header>` tag from an efficiency POV if I just end up having to write `<header class="header">` to improve efficiency.

Also in the general sense, what would your proposal be for the generic structure of selectors? Given the document below, as an example: **EDIT** I am so sorry, I forgot to state which element. In this case, what would your selector be for the `<img>` tag.

```
<header>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.google.com/" />
    </div>
</header>
```

Finally, how much does this affect the efficiency of the web page in question? Is it worth thinking about (after gzip, JS placement in the DOM, minification etc) or is it just nitpicking? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. In your first example, you'd simply use `header { }` to address the element, wouldn't you?

Comment: I have to agree with Pekka...

Comment: the header tag isnt just used for styling, this tells search engines, robots, and all devices that this is the header too

Comment: I believe Nick is asking about the fact that using a class (`.header`) is a more efficient CSS Selector than using an element (`header`), and what is gained by going from `<div class='header'>` to `<header>` if you only have to add the class anyway to make your CSS efficient.

Comment: And I was going to add info about semantics in my next comment, but it seems @RoryPickering beat me to it.

Comment: I'll also point out that that article is over two years old and that *performance* questions inherently depend on the *implementation*. Since the implementation has probably changed a lot within the last two years and moreover is different between different browsers, worrying about it is pretty pointless most of the time; unless you can clearly demonstrate a significant difference an actual end user notices in your particular app. Until then, worry about clean, simple, logical, maintainable code.

Comment: Agreed with @deceze. Worrying about the performance difference between `header` and `.header` in your CSS is the wrong thing to worry about. The difference will be so tiny it won't even register.

Comment: Notice that the end of the article linked says basically the same thing as @deceze. Worrying about the performance difference here is fretting over maybe 1ms on a massive page.

Comment: crush - if you're stating that each of these tags could save 1ms each, on a CSS stylesheet with hundreds of rules (e.g., Bootstrap CSS), that's a big deal!

Comment: @NickBull No, I'm stating that with thousands of nodes, you might save 1ms overall. This isn't 1990. Computers are fast now.

Comment: @crush Well I'm pretty sure two years ago it wasn't 1990 - why is there so many articles two years ago upon this subject if that's the way it is? Also, I'm not talking about nodes, I know computers can deal with that easily. I'm talking about 1000 different selectors matching against 1000 nodes, or are we still dealing with > 1s efficiencies?

Comment: I've been using the Internet for 18+ years and I've never once encountered a website that has been slow as a result of CSS. There are so many articles because it is a subject that authors can sell to those who obsess about premature optimization. In practice, CSS is probably the last thing you need to worry about optimizing. Today's CPUs can go through `1000 * 1000 = 1000000` iterations in nanoseconds. It takes more time to allocate the resources to iterate than to actually iterate. You'd probably be better off worrying about condensing the number of rules, rather than the selectors.

Comment: @crush thanks for the explanation - I'll try not to lose sleep over this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, selector performance is negligible for normal sized html documents. Trying to avoid writing  inefficient monster selectors (`*`, attribute- and pseudo class/element selectors) is all you need, if you don't have a high-performance site.

You won't notice the difference between `header` and `div.header` selectors, it's better to spend your time elsewhere.

Comment: Let's not forget that CSS is processed client-side as well. You have to know your audience - first rule of web design. If you know that part of your audience is still running Pentium 4 processors with IE 5, then it might be relevant to optimize your CSS. Even way back then, I can't remember a time where CSS was EVER an issue.

Comment: @crush you don't have to care for such people because their browser will render 95% of the page wrong anyway, regardless of super high performance selectors :-D